# Node.js - How to make a user profile public/private using MongoDB in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I would like to create an application where the user can set private or public for their profile. May I know how can I do it with mongoDB with Nodejs?

Comment: What have your attempted ?

Comment: I got my answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first include the npm for mongo `npm install mongodb`
In this example I also use *[monk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monk)*  `npm install monk`

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

var collection = db.get('usercollection');
collection.update({_id:"123"}, {$set: {profileStatus:"public"}});
```

**Note:** That is the code for updating in the database. Before this you need to handle if the user wants to be public or private

For more information lookup the [nodejs mongodb driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html) and the [npm site from mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

Comment: Thanks you so much!